# Shell script if-else case

Tags: shell, if-statement, logical-operators

I wrote the below script to take input interactively servername and service name. This repeats asking the inputs when y is given as input at the end of the while loop.

```
key='y';
service='';
serverName='';
while [[ $key == 'y' ]]; do
    echo -e "\nEnter serverName  : "
    read serverName
    echo -e "\nEnter Service Name  : "
    read service
    if [[ ! -z "$service" ] && [ ! -z "$serverName" ]]; then
        echo -e "startService $serverName $service"
        #echo -e " Atleast one input is null"
    else
        echo -e " Atleast one input is null"
    fi
    echo -e "Enter y to repeat this step. Enter n to exit :"
    read key
done
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I got the below error. I am new to unix scripting. please help me               ../c.sh: line 9: syntax error in conditional expression
./c.sh: line 9: syntax error near `]'
./c.sh: line 9: `    if [[ ! -z "$service" ] && [ ! -z "$serverName" ]]; then'

Comment: For ex, if i give first input as "abc" and second input "def" it should execute the if case. but i see error.

Comment: Put your error in your question. That way anyone who looks at your question sees the issue.

Comment: [[ and [ are not brackets. [[ has a meaning and [ an other, so the test doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "At least one input is null" is far less useful than "servername is null" and/or "service is null".  There is no need for an ambiguous error message here.  Also, error messages belong on stderr: `echo non-ambiguous error message >&2`

Answer (score 0):

your while loop condition is wrong correct it like below:-

```
while [[ '$key' == 'y' ]];
```

or

```
while [[ $key == y ]];
```